# php получить ассоциативный массив из параметров адресной строки?

Tags: php

есть такая строка `'sub1=1&sub2=jon'`

как из этого сделать массив

```
$params['sub1'] = 1;
$params['sub2'] = 'jon';
```

Comment: Смотрите документацию для [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), там есть примеры для извлечения аргументов адресной строки через PHP_URL_QUERY. Аналогично есть функция [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) если есть неполная адресная строка, а только аргументы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого есть готовая функция [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```php
parse_str('sub1=1&sub2=jon', $result);
print_r($result);

// Array
// (
//     [sub1] => 1
//     [sub2] => jon
// )
```

Answer (score -2):

ну, если грубо - то так:

```
$inputstr = 'sub1=1&sub2=jon';
$pairs = explode('&', $inputstr);
$params = [];
foreach($pairs as $pair)  {
    list($key, $val) = explode('=', $pair);
    $params[$key] = $val;
}
print_r($params);
```

можно более элегантно регэкспом разобрать, но приведенный пример куда как проще допилить и научить правильно реагировать на ошибки (на кривую входную строку)